# Unknown system variable 'post_content'

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Why Error - **Unknown system variable 'post_content'**

```
foreach( $posts as $post ) {

            $post_content = $this->add_image_dimensions( $post->post_content );

            if( $post_content != $post->post_content ) {

                $query = "UPDATE " . $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
                $query = " SET post_content = '" . $post_content . "' WHERE ID = " . $post->ID;

                $wpdb->query( $query );

            }
```

Sorry for my English

Comment: And note that you overwrite $query

Comment: http://2sql.ru/novosti/sql-update/ `UPDATE Planets
SET PlanetName = 'Pluton'
WHERE ID = 3` everything seems to be correct

Answer (score 0):

@Strawberry is right. You may want to do something like this:

```
    $query = "UPDATE " . $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
    $query = $query + " SET post_content = '" . $post_content . "' WHERE ID = " . $post->ID;
```

Comment: this code work `$query = "UPDATE " . $wpdb->prefix . "posts SET post_content = '" . $post_content . "' WHERE ID = " . $post->ID;`